# Read commands from test file and execute

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a shell testing program which compares the output for my program with the sample program. I have stored a list of command in a text file, it looks like this:
commands.txt:

```
echo line A > a
echo line A > b    
./program a b
```

and the shell test looks like this:

```
cat $testname | while read LINE
do  
   echo -e "$LINE$"
   $LINE
done
```

but rather than crating files a and b the program produces the flowing:

```
echo line A > a
line A > a
echo line B > b
line B > b
```

How can I execute the command just like it was written in the shell file and redirect the out put to another file?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to do that is to use `eval`:

```
cat "$testname" | while read -r; do  
   echo "$REPLY"
   eval "$REPLY"
done
```

If you just run `$LINE`, it will perform word splitting, but not I/O redirection, so it'll just pass `>` as a normal argument to `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

The shell processes redirections before word expansion, which means that the `>` inside the string is not interpreted by the shell in this context.  You need to request explicitly that the string is interpreted as a full command, like this:

```
eval "$LINE"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to write the exact same lines inside of the commands.txt file, into another file, you can say;

```
echo "$line" >> WriteTheLines.txt
```

If you would like to execute the commands inside of the commands.txt file, and write the output of the commands into another file, you can say;

```
eval "$line" >> ExecuteTheCommands.txt
```

So as an example;

```
#!/bin/bash

input="/home/commands.txt"

while read line
do
echo "$line" >> WriteTheCommands.txt
eval "$line" >> ExecuteTheCommands.txt

done<"$input"
```